PyInstaller Platformdirs is missing
I have a Streamlit python app that I would like to convert to an executable using Pyinstaller (I have the 6.6 Version and am running on a Windows machine). However, I consistently keep getting the same error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgres.py", line 158, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgres.py", line 36, in _pyi_rthook
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
  File "pkg_resources\extern\__init__.py", line 52, in create_module
  File "pkg_resources\extern\__init__.py", line 44, in load_module
ImportError: The 'platformdirs' package is required;
normally this is bundled with this package so if you get this warning,
consult the packager of your distribution.

I have tried several commands, the last being:

pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --paths=\ENV\App\Lib\site-packages --hidden-import=platformdirs app.py

